# dojo.connect with dynamic content

Tags: dojo

Is there something similar to jQuery's `live()`-method in dojo? I have some content that's being loaded with ajax, and need that content to get the same event connections.

```
dojo.query(".allTheseElements").connect("onclick", function() { /***/ }
```

And then have the dynamically loaded content fire on this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dojo.behavior`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/behavior) module can help you.

```
dojo.behavior.add({
    ".allTheseElements" : {
        "onclick" : function() {}
    }
});
```

Then after the DOM content has been changed, e.g. in the handler of you ajax requests, just call `dojo.behavior.apply()`. Dojo will apply this behavior to the newly added content incrementally.